# How to authenticate user with token (stay authenticated in iPhone)

Tags: ios, iphone, laravel, authentication, dingo-api

I have two related questions and I hope someone help me because I've been stuck for 2 days

**First: mobile phone failed to authenticate**

Here is what I have done:

1- user signs up

2- token released

3- token saved in user's device

but then when the same user try to do API requests I get

Rooute to sign up :

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');
$api->version('v1', function ($api) {
$api->post('auth/signup', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\AuthController@signup');
```

then I get a token , so I guess everything looks great!
then now when the same device sends a post request to laravel I get this message

```
"message": "Failed to authenticate because of bad credentials or an invalid authorization header."
```

this is the route to the post request

```
 $api->group(['middleware'=>'api.auth'],
    function ($api)   {
$api->post('auth/ios', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\AuthController@create');
```

**Second: is my method right to save data made by a mobile phone?**

Since I couldn't test this method I'd like to know if this is at least one of the right ways to receive data and save it. The reason to save it is because I will show it in a control panel.

```
 public function create(Request $request)
{

    $user = new User();
    $id = Auth::id();
    $user->phone = $request->input('phone');
    $user->city = $request->input('city');
    $user->street = $request->input('street');
    $user->save();

    return 'Employee record successfully created with id ' . $user->id;


}
```

Comment: If you are doing an API, please do follow some standards, like return 201 after successful creation (http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/)

Comment: I'm just testing my routes. I'll clean everything up after I finish. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are authenticate users based on api token.

Here is what you could do :

1. set up a column called `api_token` in users table by adding the following migration 
   `$table->string('api_token', 60)->unique();`.This generates a random api token for every user.
2. send the `api_token` back to the user's device and save it there
3. Send it back with every request. Preferalbly set it up globally and send it in the request Authentication request header
4. Get the authenticated user like so`$user= Auth::guard('api')->user();`

Laravel takes care of all the authentication stuff behind the scenes.

Learn More about this [here](https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51)

Comment: I have done the first three steps. but I think getting the authenticated user has been my issue. I added `$user= Auth::guard('api')->user();` but still gives me the same error. please look again at its protected routes, is there anything I am missing ? @Rahul Ravindran

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: L5.3 with dingo package

Comment: Can you tell me how are you sending the api_token back?

Comment: Using JWTAuth in my login and signup methods

`try {
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return $this->response->errorUnauthorized();
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return $this->response->error('could_not_create_token', 500);
        }
        return response()->json(compact('token'));`

Comment: Can you try HTTP headers ? 

`Authorization: Bearer {yourtokenhere}`

Comment: sorry for answering late. I think my header wasn't set up. this is my first time to use api Laravel. Thank you